# Form with nested attributes and has_many :through relationship create new record instead of using existing one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

What I try to do is a simple form for Plate where you can choose which Ingredients you want. The number and name of Ingredients may vary by day. 
Every time a new Plate is created, it created 4 new Choices with `plate_id` and `ingredient_id` and a boolean `chosen`. 
`plate_id` is from the new plate create and `ingredient_id` should be the id of the already existing ingredient in my database, and `chosen` it's if the ingredient should be in the plate.

Here is my classes Plate, Choice and Ingredient :

```
class Plate < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :choices
    has_many :ingredients, through: :choices
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :choices
end

class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :plate
    belongs_to :ingredient
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :choices
    has_many :plates, through: :choices
end
```

And my Plate nested form looks like this :

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :choices do |fc| %>
    <%= fc.check_box :chosen %>
    <%= fc.fields_for :ingredient do |fi| %>
        <%= fi.text_field(:name)%> <br />
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

And finally my Plate controller :

```
  def new
    @plate = Plate.new
    @choice1 = @plate.choices.build
    @choice2 = @plate.choices.build
    @choice3 = @plate.choices.build
    @choice4 = @plate.choices.build
    @ingredient1 = Ingredient.find_by_name('peach')
    @ingredient2 = Ingredient.find_by_name('banana')
    @ingredient3 = Ingredient.find_by_name('pear')
    @ingredient4 = Ingredient.find_by_name('apple')
    @choice1.ingredient_id = @ingredient1.id
    @choice2.ingredient_id = @ingredient2.id
    @choice3.ingredient_id = @ingredient3.id
    @choice4.ingredient_id = @ingredient4.id

  end

  def plate_params
      params.require(:plate).permit(:name, choices_attributes: [:chosen, ingredient_attributes: [ :name]])
  end
```

My problem is that when I create a new plate, it create new ingredients with same name as the chosen one (but with different id of course) and Choices had the ingredient_id of the new ingredients created.

I tried to add the `:id` in the nested attributes : 
 `params.require(:plate).permit(:name, choices_attributes: [:chosen, ingredient_attributes: [:id, :name]])` 
Bu when I do that, I go an error :

> Couldn't find Ingredient with ID=1 for Choice with ID=

I searched for answers but couldn't find any, I guess I don't know Rails params, form and nested attributes enough to understand where is the problem.

Thanks for your help ! 
*ps : It's my first question on Stack Overflow, please let my know if anything is wrong with my question*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `accepted_nested_parameters_for :ingredient` since the form isn't designed to let you create ingredients or edit ingredients.

Better that you just use `collection_select`to select an existing ingredient as part of the `choice` record (that is, just save the ingredient_id).

```
  <%= f.fields_for :choices do |fc| %>
    <%= fc.check_box :chosen %>
    <%= fc.collection_select(:ingredient_id, Ingredient.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
  <% end %>
```

And your attributes should then be...

```
params.require(:plate).permit(:name, choices_attributes: [:chosen, :ingredient_id])
```

If you just want to show the ingredient but not allow the user to change which ingredient, you can do

```
  <%= f.fields_for :choices do |fc| %>
    <%= fc.check_box :chosen %>
    <%= fc.hidden_field :ingredient_id %>
    <%= Ingredient.find(fc.object.ingredient_id).name %>
  <% end %>
```

You're finding the ingredient_id in the object encompassed by the form object `fc` and using that id to access the Ingredient, and retrieving the name attribute.

Also notice the hidden field for the `:ingredient_id` ... to make sure it's returned in the attribute hash.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I remove `accepted_nested_parameters_for :ingredient`, I can't see the ingredients name in the form. 
And if I remove `ingredient_attributes: [ :name]` in my `choices_attributes:` my created choices had empty `ingredient_id` and `plate_id`, only the boolean is saved

Comment: The `collection_select` will give you a pull-down of all ingredients by name,  and should show the current selected ingredient (by name).  Aren't you seeing that when you try it?

Comment: Sorry, I was doing something wrong... Your answer works ! Thanks ! And instead of a pull-down, is it possible to have just one ingredient, because I don't want to be able to change it, and for example select the same ingredient twice.

Comment: Yes, you could just show the ingredient name, without any selection, but then you should put the `ingredient_id` in a hidden field to ensure it gets returned in the attribute hash. I've modified the answer to show one way to do that.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you !